# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\ dt$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I need to prove that a sequence $(f_n)$ defined as $$f_n(x)=\frac{n}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\ dt$$ is uniformly convergent on every closed interval $[a,b]$.

I wanted to use Dini's theorem here (nothing else came to my mind). But to do that I need to show $f_n$ are monotonic. I attempted to calculate

$$\begin{align} 
\frac{n+1}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt - \frac{n}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\ dt=\\
\frac{n}{2}\left(\int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt - \int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\ dt\right)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt =\\
\frac{n}{2}\left(\int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt - \int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt - \int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt - \int_{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\ dt\right) + \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt =
-\frac{n}{2}\left(\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt + \int_{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}f(t)\ dt\right)+\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-\frac{1}{n+1}}^{x+\frac{1}{n+1}}f(t)\ dt
\end{align}$$
But as you see, it was not a good idea. And even if I succeeded, I still had to find pointwise limit of $f_n$...

Any thoughts?

Comment: $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Can you use this to (uniformly) estimate $\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)\,dt$?

Comment: Just by using mean value theorem? That is $\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)\,dt\leq f(\xi)\frac{2}{n}$ for $\xi \in \{x-1/n,x+1/n\}$ ? That would actually let me estimate $f_n$ by $f(\xi)$ and thus, by Weierstress theorem, making it uniformly convergent, am I correct?

Comment: No, wait, that should work if I had series $\sum f_n$. In this case it doesn't suffice. It tells me though, that pointwise limit of $f_n$ is $0$ since $\sum f_n$ converges. So now I have to check $\sup_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x)|$ if I'm thinking right.

Comment: No. Given $\epsilon>0$, you can choose $N$ so that for $n>N$ and all $x\in[a,b]$, you have $$(2/n)(f(x)-\epsilon)\le \int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n} f(t)\,dt\le (2/n)(f(x)+\epsilon).$$ Your $f_n$ converge uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: I guess, it's pretty much the same what I've been thinking about, mind the epsilon part. I thought I could estimate the integral by $(2/n)m$ and $(2/n)M$ where $m=\inf_{x\in [a,b]}f(x), M=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}f(x)$ and in this way show that the supremum I mentioned $\longrightarrow^{n\rightarrow \infty}0$ Would that be correct?

Comment: I may be misinterpreting you; but, no, $(f_n)$ *does not* converge to $0$. $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ on $[a,b]$. The integral is estimated by $(2/n) f(x)$, as I wrote in my previous comment (note of course that the integral is a function of $x$). Using the inequality in my last comment, you show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$ and all $x\in[a,b]$ the inequality $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ holds. This shows $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Comment: The integral $I_n(x)=\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}f(t)\,dt$ converges to $0$. But $I_n$ is not $f_n$; you have $f_n ={n\over 2} I_n$.

Comment: Yes, I know. Oh, I see my mistake now! Estimating the integral through $f(\xi)$ doesn't give me anything, since I don't know if $\sum f(\xi)$ converges... Thank you for your help! Now I need to think about the origins of inequality you wrote.

Comment: @DavidMitra Please consider writing your string of comments as an answer, so that this question doesn't appear to be unanswered anymore. If you choose to do so, please leave a note [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that a continuous  function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous.

So, fix $[a,b]$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Then there is a $N$ so that for $n\ge N$, we have
$$
f(x)-\epsilon\le f(t)\le f(x)+\epsilon,\  \text{for all}\ t\in[x-1/n,x+1/n]\cap[a,b].
$$

From this, and basic results on the definite integral, it follows that if $n\ge N$
$$
{2\over n}(f(x)-\epsilon)\le\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}f(t)\,dt\le{2\over n}(f(x)+\epsilon).
$$
 for all $x\in[a,b]$.

From this, we have, for $n\ge N$, that
$$
f(x)-\epsilon\le f_n(x) \le f(x)+\epsilon 
$$
 for all $x\in[a,b]$; as desired.